# Preserve Indentation in GCP Logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

Is there a way to preserve the indentation of lines in GCP logs?

I have a hard time reading scopes when every line is at the same level visually. Below is a screenshot of an example:

[image: GCP logs lacking indentation]

Comment: how do you write your logs?

Comment: These logs are from a Node.js cloud function using `console.log`, which is a common environment and method of writing logs for me. The logs in the screenshot were produced by the [helloPubSub](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub#preparing_the_application) starter code.

Comment: I have replicated your issue from the document you have mentioned. I didn’t find any logs starting with strings. I think you have made some other modifications to the code which produces the logs you referred to.  You can add a tab character '\t' to the beginning of the output string in order for it to start with a tab. This tab behavior is just created by starting strings with tab escape characters so wherever you pass in logs you can use the tab character. It will be easy to narrow down the issue if you provide some details about the code which you have modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs actually do preserve indentation, as [Srividya pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68728846/preserve-indentation-in-gcp-logs#comment121627407_68728846).

I've since edited my code, but I believe this was the result of `JSON.stringify` or some sort of string conversion function that did not preserve tabs when I printed an object.